# how to fix Expected response code 354 but got code "503"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i get { Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error: 503-"Your IP: 182.70.**.*** : Your domain example.com is not allowed in header 503-From" 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA "  }

i am using laravel mail function as well, it works perfectly.

checked my .env maildriver setup.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.*****.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME=careers@****.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

expected result : to get reset password mail

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the "from" address on config/mail.php is correct email address and exist on your server

```
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'careers@****.com'), 
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'MyAppName'),
    ],
```

remember to clear cache afterwords

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```